# Finding empty terrain rectangles in Grid-Graph

Tags: java, algorithm

The city in my game is randomly generated but is a graph of roads and intersections that can only form rectangles:

[image]

As can be seen, my terrain is pretty empty. What I want to do is find each empty rectangle and store in in a list of rectangles, forming Lots.

[image]

As you can see in this illustration, I filled in 3 'lots' and in 1 I showed the 3 rectangles it is made of.

My data structures are:

```
package com.jkgames.gta;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.RectF;

public class Intersection extends Entity
{
    Road topRoad;
    Road leftRoad;
    Road bottomRoad;
    Road rightRoad;
    Bitmap image;

    public Bitmap getImage() 
    {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Intersection(RectF rect, Bitmap image)
    {
        setRect(rect);
        setImage(image);
    }

    public Road getTopRoad() 
    {
        return topRoad;
    }

    public void setTopRoad(Road topRoad)
    {
        this.topRoad = topRoad;
    }

    public Road getLeftRoad()
    {
        return leftRoad;
    }

    public void setLeftRoad(Road leftRoad)
    {
        this.leftRoad = leftRoad;
    }

    public Road getBottomRoad() 
    {
        return bottomRoad;
    }

    public void setBottomRoad(Road bottomRoad)
    {
        this.bottomRoad = bottomRoad;
    }

    public Road getRightRoad()
    {
        return rightRoad;
    }

    public void setRightRoad(Road rightRoad) 
    {
        this.rightRoad = rightRoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext c)
    {
        c.drawRotatedScaledBitmap(image, getCenterX(), getCenterY(),
                    getWidth(), getHeight(), getAngle());
    }

}

public class Road extends Entity
{
    private Bitmap image = null;
    private Intersection startIntersection;
    private Intersection endIntersection;
    private boolean topBottom;

    public Road(RectF rect, Intersection start, Intersection end,
            Bitmap image, boolean topBottom)
    {
        setRect(rect);
        setStartIntersection(start);
        setEndIntersection(end);
        setImage(image);
        setTopBottom(topBottom);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext c)
    {
        //Rect clipRect = c.getCanvas().getClipBounds();
        //c.getCanvas().clipRect(getRect());
        float sizeW;
        float sizeH;
        if(isTopBottom())
        {
            sizeW = getWidth();
            sizeH = (sizeW / image.getWidth()) * image.getHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            sizeW = getHeight();
            sizeH = (sizeW / image.getWidth()) * image.getHeight();

        }

        int numTiles = isTopBottom() ? (int)Math.ceil(getHeight() / sizeH) :
            (int)Math.ceil(getWidth() / sizeW);

        for(int i = 0; i < numTiles; ++i)
        {
            if(isTopBottom())
            {
                c.drawRotatedScaledBitmap(
                        image,
                        getRect().left + (sizeW / 2.0f),
                        (getRect().top + (sizeH / 2.0f)) + (sizeH * i), 
                        sizeW, sizeH, 0.0f);
            }
            else
            {
                c.drawRotatedScaledBitmap(
                        image,
                        getRect().left + (sizeH / 2.0f) + (sizeH * i),
                        getRect().top + (sizeH / 2.0f), 
                        sizeW, sizeH, (float)Math.PI / 2.0f);
            }

        }

    //  c.getCanvas().clipRect(clipRect);
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() 
    {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) 
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Intersection getStartIntersection()
    {
        return startIntersection;
    }

    public void setStartIntersection(Intersection startIntersection) 
    {
        this.startIntersection = startIntersection;
    }

    public Intersection getEndIntersection()
    {
        return endIntersection;
    }

    public void setEndIntersection(Intersection endIntersection) 
    {
        this.endIntersection = endIntersection;
    }

    public boolean isTopBottom()
    {
        return topBottom;
    }

    public void setTopBottom(boolean topBottom) 
    {
        this.topBottom = topBottom;
    }
}
```

The city is a list of roads and intersections.

Is there some sort of algorithm that could generate these lots and their rectangles?

Thanks

Comment: +1 I just wanted to say, I like :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method that comes to my mind is to use a flood-fill algorithm to build up your list of regions. So basically

```
foreach square:
    if the square isn't part of a region:
        create a new empty region list
        add the square to it
        recursivly add all neighboring squares to the region
```

The end result will be that you'll have a list of regions which you can then do whatever you want with (look and see if any of the contained squares have buildings on, color in for the user, etc..).

Note: to determine whether a square is part of a region or not, I'd add a marked flag or something to the square data structure, that way when you start, you go through and clear all those flags, then as you add a square to a region you set that flag, and when you want to check to see if a square is in a region, all you need to do is check to see if that flag is set or not. That way you end up with a linear time algorithm to construct your list of regions.

As Markus pointed out in the comments here, this "flag" could be in fact a pointer/reference to a Lot object that holds the list of your squares, which would probably be convenient to have handy anyways.

Comment: I'd use a pointer to the lot-object itself. `null` means that it is not part of any lot. This will allow make it easier to find which lot a square belongs to later.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    if (x > 0 && squares[y][x].isConnectedTo(squares[y][x-1]) {
        // Connected from the left
        squares[y][x-1].getLot().addSquare(squares[y][x]);

        if (y > 0 && squares[y][x].isConnectedTo(squares[y-1][x]) {
            // Connected from both the left and above
            squares[y-1][x].getLot().mergeWith(squares[y][x].getLot());
        }
    }
    else if (y > 0 && squares[y][x].isConnectedTo(squares[y-1][x]) {
        // Connected from above
        squares[y-1][x].getLot().addSquare(squares[y][x]);
    }
    else {
        // Not connected from either
        createNewLot().addSquare(squares[y][x]);
    }
}
```

- `Lot.addSquare(…)` adds a square to the lot, and calls `setLot(…)` on the square.
- `Lot.mergeWith(…)` merges two lots, and reassigns the squares assigned to them, if they are not the same lot.
- `Square.isConnectedTo(…)` checks if they are neighbors, and that there is no road in between.

You could optimize this by using the [Disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)